# Unsemantic columns height

Tags: css, responsive-design, frameworks, grid, unsemantic-css

I use the framework "unsemantic".
When I create a grid of 4 columns, if all elements of the grid haven't the same height, the grid breaks ( from the third block ) when I reduce the window.

See here http://cemf.fr/lpem/paul-meyer/

Anyone know how to fix this?

Html :

```
<article class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100"> 
    /* MY CONTENT HERE */
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya it is happening because of the height of your first column.

One way is to create `grid-container` for every row.

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <article class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100"> 
        /* MY CONTENT HERE */
    </article>
    <article class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100"> 
        /* MY CONTENT HERE */
    </article>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
    <article class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100"> 
        /* MY CONTENT HERE */
    </article>
    <article class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100"> 
        /* MY CONTENT HERE */
    </article>
</div>
```

Other way is to use `clear` on your third column ..

Add a class like.

```
 .article-jury:nth-child(3n){
    clear:both; 
   }
```

and add in class for the third column

```
 <div class="grid-container">
    <article class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100"> 
        /* MY CONTENT HERE */
    </article>
    <article class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100"> 
        /* MY CONTENT HERE */
    </article>
    <article class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 clearColumns"> 
        /* MY CONTENT HERE */
    </article>
    <article class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100"> 
        /* MY CONTENT HERE */
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I work with Wordpress so the content is dynamic, how can I specify a clear on my third column ?

Comment: @Kéryh Both ways it will align your grid the way you want..Irrespective of the length of the columns(Dynamic shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I just wanted how can I add a class to the third element... But I use Jquery and it works ! Thanks al lot.
`$(".article-jury:nth-child(3n)").addClass("clearColumns")`

Comment: ya no problem.i suggest using css way.i see that you added script at the top of page.this hinder's your page loading time.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how to combine `nth-child` and `:after`... Or I don't use the right method.

Comment: Woops... That simple ! Thanks a lot for your help