# Foundation grid alignment of multiple row

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a problem on repeating foundation "medium 4 column".when it goes second line the grid behave extraordinary..
take a look on my [link1](http://demo.mejorainfotech.com/dev/ledlight/?page_id=307)
in chrome it starts from right in second row..and in Firefox it brakes.
Also the equalizer not working on this page..it working on other pages like  [link2](http://demo.mejorainfotech.com/dev/ledlight/)

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Sai Ram Sudheer does have a correct answer when it comes to Foundation's 12 column grid, you should also take a look into the [block-grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Foundation framework has default 12 column grid structure.

Best way to use is by having `row` class for every 12 columns.

### issue :

[image]

If you look at your second column-RECESSED GIMBLE DOWN LIGHT WIDE LENS. It occupies more height when compared to rest of the columns in that row. So the product2 which has float:left cannot float to the start of the row.

### Solution:

1.use `row` class for every 12 columns.

2.if you have complex grid structure and you connot go with `row` class use `clear:both` on product2 to align it in the new row.

Check this answer its not based on `foundation` but similar problem --[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934800/unsemantic-columns-height/25935273#25935273)