# Zurb foundation grid - repeating columns without row

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Is it wrong to do it like this?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
</div>
```

From what I can see the result is the same but with less `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct. Adding .row is useful because it keeps things even and clears out the previous floats. Take this example at the small breakpoint where it switches the divs to 50% (Assuming a 12-column grid):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
</div>
```

In the above example, when it runs into small the grid will be 2, 1, 2, and 1. Now do it with one row:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
</div>
```

This example will now break down into 2, 2, and 2. If you're having floating issues with the 2nd example, [Foundation's Equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html) is a great way to fix those issues.

Comment: I would add that both ways work, and that the second way is technically what Zurb (and Twitter/Bootstrap for that matter) endorses in the docs. If you change your layout and column widths aren't equaling 100%, the whole thing breaks without interposing rows.

Comment: Good point. I've been using Foundation's Equalizer for so long that I forgot about floating issues. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">some content</div>
</div>
```

A few things this structure does are:

1. round off for widths - browser render widths % differently..so
   most frameworks have a `float :opposite` direction property to
   `column:last-child` in the row so that the last columns in all rows
   align in a line.
2. Row is used to clear floats in the layout..
         Ex: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941549/foundation-grid-allignment-of-multiple-row/25956836#25956836)

in the link above The alignment is messed up because of the  unequal height in columns.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">some content</div>
</div>
```

There is nothing wrong in using this structure.

There are layouts in which you cannot go with new row for every 12 columns as given in the other answer.

If you run into alignment issues as in the question I posted above (that would the only main difference between both the structures). Have custom classes to clear them.